# Can .NET website access C drive, add vba macros to ms office and enable Macros Security in Outlook?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office, office-interop

This is the scenario:

There's an intranet website that stores a set of macros (Outlook addons). Now I want a user to visit, choose the one they're interested in (Language) and have it installed into their Outlook.

I first need to find the right folder of course, some users still have old images and their Outlook Profile lives in Windows/Microsoft. Some of them use 2003, some 2010 but majority is on 2007.

So the questions are as follows: Can I...

- use .NET WEBSITE to navigate to user's C:/.. drive ?
- install new macros ?
- enable Outlook's Macros security ?

EDIT:

I'm trying to overcome the procedure where user connects to my shared folder, runs 12345.bat , then get a command prompt window on which they have a number of options : different versions of Office/ Language etc, this of course requires them to close down all office apps, and enabling macros- restarting outlook again...

This is just too painful and leaves me with no visibility of who has installed, whether it worked or not. Possible erros etc

Comment: If you want to distribute Outlook Addons, why don't you just provide a download for an installer or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the user download an installation program. Accessing the C:\ drive from a website is not allowed, for obvious reasons.

Comment: If your security is tight enough to not allow you run an exe (even with explicit permission), I don't see any way to get your files onto disk, other than manually downloading them by a user.

Comment: Actually, thinking out loud, when they can run .bat file from shared folder on my PC, they could as well run it from the actual server, but instead of double clicking .bat they would just click the button on the page, i'm getting all confused here. Is that going to break the security in any way? Let's say files would live in actual application folder... i feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: No, you can't run a .bat file from a website. You will need to get the user to download something.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse not because of security reasons. User needs to download and install/run/whatever your file. You can create an executable that is installable or runnable and make the user download it.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**
You can't do it over HTTP, but on an intranet, with correctly set up permissions you can totally write this because the server can have direct access to the C-drive of the client without having to make the client do any of the work.

**Full Explanation**

A website cannot touch a client's harddrive using client side technologies (javascript, etc).  The security issues would be enormous.  **However** a server can totally touch its own harddrive, ***and*** the drives of other computers on its intranet it has permissions to.

If you set up your intranet correctly you could design the website simply as a 'trigger' to running a script that modified the user's computer over the intranet, rather than directly through the website.

Comment: No JS, definitely not! I meant server side code. Where should I start ? / What should I look for ? some sort of office library, perhaps ?

Comment: I'd probably just write a program that did it for the computer it's on, then make the server send it to the computer, make the server execute it on the computer, and make the server clean up after itself when it's done...